# I get error in the AndroidManifest.xml file when i try to run my code on my phone.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am a beginner working on a small project. Every time I tried to run the code, it ended up with this error. I have already tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it as well. Please help me.

Comment: upload the error please

Comment: Please paste the error as well as the AndroidManifest File.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just goto file menu and selects the invalidate cache / restart it will help you to rebuilding the AndroidManifest file again